# notifyItemRemoved of recyclerView in loop bugs?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When I remove some item in RecyclerView, but it comes to a bug, the bug is hard to occur,but it will occur sometimes. Sometimes the item is not deleted, and still show in recyclerView and can not remove forever. Below is my code:

```
//the positions is a collection,which collect my item positions that should be removed.

int realPosition;
int temp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++) {
    realPosition = positions.get(i) - temp;
    getAdapter().remove(realPosition);
    getAdapter().notifyItemRemoved(realPosition);
    temp++;
}
```

and my English is poor, hope you can understand. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove items from recycler view with in loop then try this

```
int realPosition;
int temp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++) {
    realPosition = positions.get(i) - temp;
    getAdapter().remove(realPosition);
    temp++;
}
getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The problem with your code is that each time your loop runs recyclerView's positions get updated so your notifyItemRemoved(realPosition) is removing something other than what you actually want....Hope this helps

Comment: THX very much! And finally I get the better way  `for(int i = positions.size() - 1: i >=0; i--)`

Comment: If this has helped you please consider upvoting or marking my answer as answer